# PHP JSON response doesn't validate

Tags: php, json

I am trying to cache a JSON API response, so I am not constantly hitting the Meetup API server:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$cURL = curl_init();
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.meetup.com/2/events?back&fields=event_hosts&group_urlname=$group_urlname&page=999&api&key=$api_key");
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
echo json_encode(json_decode(curl_exec($cURL)))
```

This outputs the JSON fine but it doesn't not validate. The JSON code looks like this:

```
{"results":[{"status":"upcoming","visibility":"public","maybe_rsvp_count":0,"venue":{"id":20151862,"lon":-0.080918,"repinned":false,"name":"ISTD2 DANCE STUDIOS, ","address_1":"346 Old Street, EC1V 9NQ ","lat":51.526608,"country":"gb","city":"London"},"event_hosts":[{"member_name":"Ram Maree","member_id":12204723},{"member_name":"Jon","member_id":62369612},{"member_name":"David Murray","member_id":126425602}],"fee":{"amount":5,"description":"per person","label":"Price","required":"0","accepts":"paypal","currency":"GBP"},"id":"220172436","utc_offset":0,"duration":5400000,"time":1423594800000,"waitlist_count":0,"updated":1423429374000,"yes_rsvp_count":20,"created":1422568871000,"event_url":"http:\/\/www.meetup.com\/Public-Speaking-for-Dummies\/events\/220172436\/"
```

When I run through http://jsonlint.com/ the code doesn't validate. I receive a Parse error like:

> Parse error on line 420: ...       "event_url": "http://www.meetup
>   -----------------------^ Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '['

Does any one know how I can use PHP to return the JSON API in the correct format?

In addition, when I visit the JSON api call directly the JSON does validate. So the problem occurs once PHP gets involved.

Comment: Your JSON is incomplete; it is missing plenty of `}` and `]`.

Comment: It doesn't validate, because (at least) the closing portion is missing.
Check if curl is indeed getting the entire response from the server before continuing.

Comment: Like @SalmanA said, if you add the missing brackets, it validates just fine :-)

Comment: PS: Why are you encoding and decoding the JSON? You should probably echo `$json_string` as-is.

Comment: This might be a network connectivity related issue...

Comment: Thanks for your prompt responses. I didn't paste all of the code as was too long so that's why the closing brackets were missing. I have echo $json_strong as it is and the PHP output code can be viewed here: http://jsfiddle.net/londonfed/ehhjsed4/

Comment: When I run the code from JS FIDDLE through http://www.jslint.com/ - I get the following message:

JSON: bad.

line 1 character 5634Unsafe character.

Comment: I'm seeing some `Â` in that JSON, points to a character encoding issue. Either the API is returning invalid JSON, or you're mistreating the JSON somewhere in copy and pasting it.

Comment: Yes the dodgy chracters is because I didn't use json_encode. When I encode I get the following format: http://jsfiddle.net/londonfed/ehhjsed4/1/ - which returns an error. Please note the JSON api call works fines/validates before PHP.

Comment: You're already getting a JSON string, you don't *encode* a JSON string into JSON again. If anything, do this: `echo json_encode(json_decode(curl_exec($cURL)))`. See if PHP complains. If this works, there's no issue with the JSON itself.

Comment: Thanks a lot Deceze that worked great. I have updated the main code with your fix.